# rendering a json with direction service

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

when i make a request for a specific latlang direction service responses with the same json. so instead of making the same requests always, i want to store the json somehow.i tried parsing the json and sent to my function which i render the responses, but it didn't work. is something like this even possible?

```
var direction = JSON.parse('{"routes":[{"bounds":......}');
directionRenderer.setDirections(direction);
```

Comment: [this post](http://www.stowaway.net/view/blog/item/gmaps_and_storing_di/1893) seems promising (haven't tried it).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible by using `directionRenderer.setDirections()` , because not all properties of a directionsResult may be stored in JSON.

But you may of course draw the route on your own, fetch the important details (LatLng's, descriptions etc. out of the directionsResult and use them to 1. draw a polyline and 2. providing route-details)