# Caching Google maps routes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, caching, google-maps-api-3, github-pages

I've got a geojson file with a bunch of points. I use Google Maps to get routing information between these points (using the JS API v3). Unfortunately I'm getting the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error status back because I'm doing too many routing requests at a time.

For now I've solved it by delaying my routing requests. But that is not a long term solution. It takes too long to draw the full route now.

What I want to do is cache the routes. The only time I'd need to invalidate the cache is when the geojson file is updated (let's say this happens once a week maybe).

It's a static site. So all the logic is client side JavaScript. The site is hosted as a GitHub project page.

Any ideas on how I could implement the caching? Could Jekyll (github pages tool) help in any way? I don't know exactly what it does. Or some Travis-CI script?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify; It'd be enough to cache just the polyline and then draw that. I don't need the actual driving directions. I also don't need to be able to edit the route by drag-n-drop.

Comment: you may want to take a look at the [Terms of Services of Maps Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms). Search for (b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content and check if what you are trying to do is not violating the TOS (before you invest too much time on your app)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but I think I'm fine. The very first exemption from the rule is "except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation" which is exactly my goal.

Comment: [one option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985322/how-to-reliably-reproduce-the-gmap-route-between-two-points) (but would just be the polyline, none of interactive functionality). [another option discussed in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721218/rendering-a-json-with-direction-service/)

Comment: The polyline is enough. But the real question is how to store it since github pages doesn't provide you with a database to store anything in.

Comment: So, is it ok to store the polyline, according to google's TOS? I mean, its just a line, not "real" point/place information.

Comment: To get a proper answer to that question I think you'd have to ask a lawyer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to write a node.js script that generates a polyline file with the route. Then I just draw that polyline on the map. The route changes seldom enough that I don't mind that it's a manual step.

It's been a year, but I think this is the final version of the script that generates the polyline: https://github.com/Tobbe/highpointing/blob/master/lib/route_creator.js

Answer (score 2):

- You can choose to use cookies for client side data storage.
  Store a date and the polypoints array in cookie and when no cookie/ out of date, make a request, otherwise just draw poly on the map.

I would say use php or something and store it on server, I know You don't want that.